# FragmentStatePager instantiate my Fragment twice

Tags: android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am using the following the custom viewPager with FragmentStatePagerAdapter to create a set of fragments for user to write the specific profile. The data of the user can be retrieved by SQL with respect to the position of the child page of the viewpager. When it comes to the execution , I see that the fragment is created twice whenever the first time to be load and swipe to the other uncached pages . I have found the referenceFragment Hash map to retrieve the current fragment to be load once only instead of two fragments to be loaded. COuld you please tell me the better way to load the fragment once only ?

The below is my working :

```
static SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    static CustomViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(fm);       
        dotsCount = mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount();
        dots = new  ImageView[dotsCount];
        dots[0] = dot1;
        dots[1] = dot2;
        dots[2] = dot3;
        dots[3] = dot4;
        dots[4] = dot5;     
        dots[5] = dot6;     
        dots[6] = dot7;     
        setUiPageViewController();
        isTablet=  ReadExcel.isTabletDevice(this);
        mViewPager = (CustomViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);        
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setEnabled(true);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(viewPagerPageChangeListener);

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment  {

        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        //  PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();

            PlaceholderFragment fragment =  ((SectionsPagerAdapter)mViewPager.getAdapter()).getFragment(sectionNumber);
            if(fragment==null){
                fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            }
            Bundle args = new Bundle(); 
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setTag(String.valueOf(sectionNumber));
            fragment.setArguments(args);            


            return fragment;
        }

        public  String getFTag(){
            return tag;
        }

        public void setTag(String tag) {
            this.tag = tag;
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState); 

....}}

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {


        private Map<Integer, PlaceholderFragment> mPageReferenceMap = new HashMap<Integer, PlaceholderFragment>();


        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            return PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;
        }


        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            for(int i = 0; i < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); ++i) {
                fm.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);                        
            } 


            PlaceholderFragment pf =  PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position);
            mPageReferenceMap.put(Integer.valueOf(position), pf);

            return pf;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
            mPageReferenceMap.remove(Integer.valueOf(position));

            // mPageReferenceMap.remove(position);
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment getFragment(int key) {

            return mPageReferenceMap.get(key);
        }



        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 7;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```